# Convert pfx file to base64 encoded Public key PEM file

Tags: openssl, certificate, client-certificates, pfx

I am new to certificates and keys.
I have been given a pfx file and the requirement is to extract the public key in a base64 encoded PEM file.

I've used the below command to extract the Private Key:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certname.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes
```

I've used the below command to extract the certificate:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in certname.pfx -nokeys -out cert.pem
```

The Public certificate using

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certname.pfx -nodes -clcerts -nokeys | openssl x509 -out public.crt
```

But how do I get the Public key? And how to encode in base64?

Answer (score 0):

The [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) format is a base64 formatted certificate.  So the "public" key should be in the "cert.pem" file generated (along with all chain certificates as well).  You can open this file in a text editor to see it.

If you need just the public key certificate by itself you can run the following command.

> openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nokeys -clcerts -out public.pem

You can see why by looking up the [openssl documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs12.html) for the arguments used:

> -clcerts
>
> Only output client certificates (not CA certificates).
>
> -nokeys
>
> No private keys will be output.
>
> -out filename
>
> The filename to write certificates and private keys to, standard
>   output by default. They are all written in PEM format.

If there are no chain certificates in the PFX, the above command will output the same pem file as the cert.pem file generated.

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
openssl base64 -in <infile> -out <outfile>
```